# How can I generate a range of numbers with text using Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a table 'content' with the column name 'info' with each line inserted with the text "Record number 1" up to "Record number 100".

I've created the table and column so far with this code but I'm not sure how to generate the range:

```
CREATE TABLE content (info TEXT);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This can be done using `generate_series` in following way.

  ```
    create table content (info text); 

    insert into content
    select concat('Record number ', generate_series(1, 100));  

    select * from content;
  ```
- Here's DB [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aXv1L8TWvGKL7y4C4oRT6C/0)